# Choosing one of two pure virtual functions in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, pure-virtual

Is there a way for a derived class to choose to implement one of two pure virtual functions?

In my case, these pure virtual functions serve the same general purpose, but in certain settings of the class, one will require the function with an additional parameter. Of course there is always the option of making one pure virtual function with the full parameter set. However in this case there will always be the possibility of the end-user wondering about this extra parameter he isn't using.

Comment: "Is there a way for a derived class to choose to implement one of two pure virtual functions?" No.

Comment: No you cant do that. The compiler needs to know that that function exists in the child class. Sounds like you need to rethink your design a little. If you can expand a little on the problem this is supposed to solve then some suggestions might be possible. Sounds like at the moment you are stuck in an XY problem.

Comment: A pure virtual method must be implemented in the derived class that wanted to be instantiated. Overriding the pure virtual method means adding a method to derived class with the same `signature` (Number and type of parameters and order of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pure virtual functions must be implemented in each subclass.

However, you can address your particular issue by defining a single pure virtual function with a full set of parameters, and adding a default for the last parameter that you consider optional:

```
virtual void foo(int p1, std::string p2, double p3 = 0.0) = 0;
```

Now the callers would have a choice of passing two or three parameters, while implementing classes that do not need `p3` would be able to ignore it.

Comment: you missing a `virtual`?

Comment: However it is in general discouraged to use default parameters with virtual functions, as they might behave in a very non-intuitive way (for example, if derived func uses a different default value or does not provide default, it depends on how the instance is typed what default parameter value will be used or whether it will compile at all). The common pattern is to have non-virtual public function with default parameters and calling the protected virtual function with the full set of parameters from there.

Comment: what if they have different return types?